# Displaying JSON imageURL into UITableView using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json, imageurl

I am currently trying to display the JSON data on to my UITableView. I've created a separate class which handles and declares the data being extracted from the API. I also created a custom cell to display the data. However I am not sure how to display the images of the API. I was able to display the title of the API using just a standard TableViewController without custom cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = recipes = [indexPath.row].title

    return cell
}
```

but when trying to create a custom cell the **image** uses an imageURL which works differently. Other tutorials and demo don't seem to be using **Alamofire** and **SwiftyJSON**.

I did read the documentation: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration but still not sure how to solve this issue. Please tell me how you'd get the API data to display on my table.

Class

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

    class Recipe {

        var title: String!
        var image: URL?


        init(json: JSON) {
            self.title = json["title"].stringValue
            self.image = json["image"].url

        }


    }
```

CustomCell

```
import UIKit

class RecipeCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView?



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Alamofire.request(searchURL, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).response { [unowned self] response in
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
        let json = JSON(data: data)

        for recipe in json.arrayValue {
            let newRecipe = Recipe(json: recipe)
            self.recipes.append(newRecipe)


        }

        for recipe in self.recipes {
            print(recipe.title)
            print(recipe.image)

        }



    }


}

// Display JSON Data into the tableView

 func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipes.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeCell", for: indexPath)

    // What to write here?

    return cell
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you have to make the extension of Imageview as

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
 }
```

then you have to write cellForRowAt method as

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeCell", for: indexPath)
    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    let imagePath = recipe.image
    cell.titleLabel.text = recipe.title
    cell. imgView.downloadedFrom(link: imagePath)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: don't forget to reload the table when you get response from server

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use the extension and get the imageURL to be recognised in the UIImageView.